# Google sheet Sumproduct with importrange of unique values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data in two sheets (Source Sheet and Result Sheet). I want to import the unique values based on two columns of the source sheet into result sheet along with the product of two columns based on unique value. For more clarity I had entered test data in the Source Sheet with the expected outcome in the Result Sheet. The links of both the sheets are as below

**Source sheet** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13biwAB46kswhIIiLnO-Nn9B8Vf5AAPghsY9YZrYJ470/edit#gid=0

**Result Sheet** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p9ejduRsFxxDA7vgnO0Y9Wt8Vc9Kwb-gSlhoW1T-ESo/edit#gid=0

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions should be self-contained. Considering this, please add all the relevant details directly into the question body including some sample data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `QUERY()` function with `IMPORTRANGE()`.

```
=QUERY(QUERY(
IMPORTRANGE("13biwAB46kswhIIiLnO-Nn9B8Vf5AAPghsY9YZrYJ470","Sheet1!A2:D"),
"select Col1, Col2, Col3*Col4 
label Col3*Col4 ''"),
"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) 
group by Col1, Col2 
label sum(Col3) ''")
```

If you use ***E Column*** in source sheet then you can use only one query-

```
=QUERY(
IMPORTRANGE("13biwAB46kswhIIiLnO-Nn9B8Vf5AAPghsY9YZrYJ470","Sheet1!A2:E"),
"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col5)
where Col5 is not null
group by Col1, Col2
label sum(Col5) ''")
```

[image]